# Cast a List of object to another List

Tags: c#, .net

I have two model class:

```
public class SalesItem
{
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public double UnitPrice { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class ProductItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public double UnitPrice { get; set; } 
}
```

I have a list of SalesItem, `List<ProductItem> products`, how can I cast it to `List<SalesItem> sales`

---

EDITED

```
List<ProductItem> salesList = new List<ProductItem>();
List<SalesItem> salesItem = salesList.Cast<SalesItem>();
```

Error:

```
Connot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Model.SalesItem>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.SalesItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?
```

Comment: how to fill quantity of sales item

Comment: Are the classes `ProductItem` and `SalesItem` related (e.g. one inherits from the other?) If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tried and tested**

Include namespace

```
using System.Linq;
```

and then

```
List<ProductItem> yourProductlist = new List<ProductItem>();

yourProductlist.Add(new ProductItem() { ProductName = "A", UnitPrice = 50 });
yourProductlist.Add(new ProductItem() { ProductName = "B", UnitPrice = 150 });

List<SalesItem> yourSaleslist = yourProductlist.Select(x => 
                           new SalesItem() { ProductName = x.ProductName, 
                                             UnitPrice = x.UnitPrice }).ToList();
```

**See it working**

[image]

**Casting will work if ProductItem is inherited from SalesItem class**

Answer (score 2):

In the example you have given, you cannot cast between these two types because they have nothing in common with each other. The right way to do it would be to have a `baseItem` class and then a `derivedItem` class that inherits from `baseItem`. Then you can do:

```
List<baseItem> baseList;
List<derivedItem> derivedList = baseList.Cast<derivedItem>();
```

This is usually referred to as **downcasting**, and is often an indicator of an improper hierarchy in your code, so I suggest limiting its usage.

Comment: This doesn't work unless you add a `.ToList()` after the `.Cast<>()`.

Comment: the problem is ProductItem inherit INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change `SalesItem` to inherit from `ProductItem`, and then you can use LINQ, like that:

```
List<ProductItem> products;
IEnumerable<SalesItem> salesItems = products.Cast<SalesItem>();
```

or

```
List<SalesItem> salesItems = products.Cast<SalesItem>().ToList();
```

Don't forget to ensure you have the following in the file, for the `Cast` extension method to be available:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: This doesn't work unless you add a `.ToList()` after the `.Cast<>()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can define what the value of `defaultQuantity` is, because it doesn't exist in `ProductItem`.

```
List<SalesItem> sales = products.ConvertAll(x => new SalesItem() {
                            ProductName = x.ProductName,
                            Quantity = defaultQuantity, 
                            UnitPrice = x.UnitPrice  
                        });
```